# How to restrict SSLEngine to TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8 CipherSuite?

Tags: java, bouncycastle, sslengine

I have the following code:

```
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, null);
SSLEngine sslEngine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
String[] suites = { "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8" };
sslEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**:
I found that I should use `BouncyCastleJsseProvider` which require a `SecureRandom` object, like this:

```
sslContext.init(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers(), null, new SecureRandom());
```

After using the new provider, I'm getting the following stacktrace in my code base, as I understand, it should work as before:

```
Aug 17, 2017 8:47:32 PM org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsServer notifyAlertRaised
INFO: Server raised fatal(2) handshake_failure(40) alert: Failed to read record
org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsFatalAlert: handshake_failure(40)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.AbstractTlsServer.getSelectedCipherSuite(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvTlsServer.getSelectedCipherSuite(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsServerProtocol.sendServerHelloMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsServerProtocol.handleHandshakeMessage(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processHandshakeQueue(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.processRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.RecordStream.readRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.safeReadRecord(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.tls.TlsProtocol.offerInput(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.ProvSSLEngine.unwrap(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Were you able to get this to work? I'm running into the same error (with the same cipher, fwiw!). Thanks!

Comment: I posted the answer on how I got it working, hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did the following in order to get it working.

- Add providers: `BouncyCastleProvider` and `BouncyCastleJsseProvider`

  ```
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider());
  ```
- Create `SSLContext` using `BouncyCastleJsseProvider`

  ```
  SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
  ```
- Initialize the `sslContext` using an instance of `SecureRandom` with `BouncyCastleProvider`

  ```
  sslContext.init(
          keyManagers,
          trustManagers,
          SecureRandom.getInstance("DEFAULT", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME));
  ```
- You might need to create the `KeyManagerFactory` with `BouncyCastleJsseProvider` and `PKIX` algorithm

  ```
  KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX", BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
  ```
- Now, we are able to enable the cipher suite

  ```
  SSLEngine sslEngine = sslContext.createSSLEngine();
  String[] suites = { "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8" };
  sslEngine.setEnabledCipherSuites(suites);
  ```

Comment: Thank you! 

I had done all the necessary, except for adding the BCJSSE *and* the BCJCE provider! Sigh!

For what it is worth, the only place where you need to specify the BouncyCastle Provider when getting instances, is when getting the SSLContext instance. The rest can be the default ones returned.